# NullPointerException Force Close on Line 65 - saveContact(); - evaluating a variable that is null [Noob Warning]

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sqlite

Issue: Force Close on Line 65 - saveContact();

Notes:

Hi everyone - I'm trying to save a bit of data in my database and the application keeps crashing. I'm a bit new with all this so I was wondering if someone could explain what I'm doing wrong. I'm sure it's something simple... but I have no idea how to fix it.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

NoobNinja

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.FrameLayout;
    import android.widget.TimePicker;

    public class AddEditCountry extends Activity {

         private long rowID; 
         private EditText nameEt;
         private EditText capEt;
         private EditText codeEt;
         private TimePicker timeEt;
         private TimePicker minEt;
         public static final String KEY_BUNDLE_TIME = "time";
         public static final String KEY_BUNDLE_MIN = "min";

           @Override
           public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
           {
              super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
              setContentView(R.layout.add_country);

              nameEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameEdit);
              capEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.capEdit);
              codeEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.codeEdit);
              timeEt = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timeEdit);
              minEt = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.minEdit);


              Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 

              if (extras != null)
              {
                 rowID = extras.getLong("row_id");
                 nameEt.setText(extras.getString("name"));  
                 capEt.setText(extras.getString("cap"));  
                 codeEt.setText(extras.getString("code"));
                 timeEt.setCurrentHour(extras.containsKey(KEY_BUNDLE_TIME) ? extras.getInt(KEY_BUNDLE_TIME) : 0);
                 minEt.setCurrentMinute(extras.getInt("min"));
              }

              Button saveButton =(Button) findViewById(R.id.saveBtn);
              saveButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                  public void onClick(View v) 
                  {
                     if (nameEt.getText().length() != 0)
                     {
                        AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object> saveContactTask = 
                           new AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object>() 
                           {
                              @Override
                              protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) 
                              {
                                 saveContact();
                                 return null;
                              }

                              @Override
                              protected void onPostExecute(Object result) 
                              {
                                 finish();
                              }
                           }; 

                        saveContactTask.execute((Object[]) null); 
                     }

                     else
                     {
                        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(AddEditCountry.this);
                        alert.setTitle(R.string.errorTitle); 
                        alert.setMessage(R.string.errorMessage);
                        alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.errorButton, null); 
                        alert.show();
                     }
                  } 
             });
           }


               private void saveContact() 
               {
                  DatabaseConnector dbConnector = new DatabaseConnector(this);

                  if (getIntent().getExtras() == null)
                  {
                      dbConnector.insertContact(nameEt.getText().toString(),
                              capEt.getText().toString(),
                              timeEt.getCurrentHour().toString(),
                              minEt.getCurrentMinute().toString(),
                              codeEt.getText().toString(),
                              timePicker.getCurrentHour().toString(),
                              timePicker.getCurrentMinute().toString());

                  }
                  else
                  {
                     dbConnector.updateContact(rowID,
                        nameEt.getText().toString(),
                        capEt.getText().toString(),
                        timeEt.getCurrentHour().toString(),
                        minEt.getCurrentMinute().toString(),/* Storing as String*/
                        codeEt.getText().toString());
                  }
               }
    }














    import android.content.ContentValues;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.SQLException;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;



    public class DatabaseConnector {

        public static final String KEY_BUNDLE_TIME = "time";
        public static final String KEY_BUNDLE_MIN = "min";
        private static final String DB_NAME = "WorldCountries";
        private SQLiteDatabase database;
        private DatabaseOpenHelper dbOpenHelper;

        public DatabaseConnector(Context context) {
            dbOpenHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        }

           public void open() throws SQLException 
           {
              //open database in reading/writing mode
              database = dbOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
           } 

           public void close() 
           {
              if (database != null)
                 database.close();
           }       

           public void insertContact(String name, String cap, String code, String time, String min) 
                   {
                      ContentValues newCon = new ContentValues();
                      newCon.put("name", name);
                      newCon.put("cap", cap);
                      newCon.put("time", time);
                      newCon.put("min", min);
                      newCon.put("code", code);
                      newCon.put(AddEditCountry.KEY_BUNDLE_TIME, time);
                      newCon.put(AddEditCountry.KEY_BUNDLE_MIN, min);

                      open();
                      database.insert("country", null, newCon);
                      close();
                   }


                   public void updateContact(long id, String name, String cap,String code, String time, String min) 
                   {
                      ContentValues editCon = new ContentValues();
                      editCon.put("name", name);
                      editCon.put("cap", cap);
                      editCon.put("time", time);
                      editCon.put("min", min);
                      editCon.put("code", code);
                      editCon.put(AddEditCountry.KEY_BUNDLE_TIME, time);
                      editCon.put(AddEditCountry.KEY_BUNDLE_MIN, min);
                      open();
                      database.update("country", editCon, "_id=" + id, null);
                      close();
                   }


                   public Cursor getAllContacts() 
                   {
                      return database.query("country", new String[] {"_id", "name"}, 
                         null, null, null, null, "name");
                   }

                   public Cursor getOneContact(long id) 
                   {
                      return database.query("country", null, "_id=" + id, null, null, null, null);
                   }

                   public void deleteContact(long id) 
                   {
                      open(); 
                      database.delete("country", "_id=" + id, null);
                      close();
                   }
    }


PROBLEMS:


timePicker cannot be resolved   AddEditCountry.java line 104
minEdit cannot be resolved or is not a field    AddEditCountry.java line 37 
timePicker cannot be resolved   AddEditCountry.java line 103
```

Answer (score 1):

I think problem is this line:

```
minEt.getCurrentMinute().toString()
```

You are trying to get data from `TimePicker` that is assigned to `NULL`:

```
private TimePicker minEt;
```

and this is reason why your application crashed. Solution is to initialise your TimePicker and it should works. So remove comment from line where your initialising it.

Comment: When I dont comment it out I'm getting the error "Description Resource minEdit cannot be resolved or is not a field." (which is why I had it commented out in the first place [testing purposes]

Comment: @NoobNinja but now your timepicker is not initialized so you cannot get data from it.

Comment: So what should I do about the error I get when I don't comment it out?

Comment: @NoobNinja remove comment, type ctrl+s and tell mi full error log.

Comment: I'm getting 3 errors - one on each of the lines you had me add - and one when uncommenting out minEdit 


minEdit cannot be resolved or is not a field AddEditCountry.java  line 37 Java Problem
The method getText() is undefined for the type View AddEditCountry.java line 103 Java Problem
The method getText() is undefined for the type View AddEditCountry.java line 104 Java Problem

Comment: @NoobNinja because timepicker dont have method getText() you can use `timePicker.getCurrentHour().toString();` or `timePicker.getCurrentMinute().toString();`.

Comment: I added those two lines and now I'm getting 2 timePicker cannot be resolved errors as well as the original minEdit cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: @NoobNinja you still have commented line with minEt.

Comment: I apologize  I meant I was getting those errors on my machine - I've updated the code above.

Comment: Help! (I really need a hand with this)

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the data in any of the fields?  The stacktrace you supply says it is due to an NPE at line 101

```
03-24 00:49:10.643: E/AndroidRuntime(6809):     at com.nfc.linkingmanager.AddEditCountry.saveContact(AddEditCountry.java:101)
```

Without knowing just which lines or area, I'm only guessing, but you could change your saveContact to use:

```
findViewById(R.id.nameEdit).getText().toString()
```

as in:

```
dbConnector.insertContact(
   findViewById(R.id.nameEdit).getText().toString(),
   findViewById(R.id.nameEdit).getText().toString().getText().toString(),
   etc...
```

Basically, one of your vars is null and you're trying to use it.

Comment: I added   dbConnector.insertContact(nameEt.getText().toString(),
                    capEt.getText().toString(),
                    timeEt.getCurrentHour().toString(),
                    minEt.getCurrentMinute().toString(),
                    codeEt.getText().toString(),
                    findViewById(R.id.nameEdit).getText().toString(),
                    findViewById(R.id.nameEdit).getText().toString().getText().toString());

but I'm getting a problem stating "The method getText() is undefined for the type View AddEditCountry.java line 10

Comment: ok, you'll need casting to get it to work, but I think @Sajmon's post is what you need to follow through with.